# digiKam 3.3.0 install

Tags: software-installation, compiling, digikam

So let me start by saying I'm new to Ubuntu and am yet to successfully install anything from a tarball...

I'm trying to install the digiKam 3.3.0 software package and after finally getting open CV 4.2.6 to install (which gave me a lot of problems when initially trying to install this digiKam 3.3.0)

I'm getting this message after:

```
sudo checkinstall  --pkgname=digiKam3.2 --install=no  make install
```

I get this message:

```
Scanning dependencies of target kface
[  3%] Building CXX object extra/libkface/libkface/CMakeFiles/kface.dir/kface_automoc.cpp.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so', needed by `lib/libkface.so.2.0.0'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [extra/libkface/libkface/CMakeFiles/kface.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

****  Installation failed. Aborting package creation.

Restoring overwritten files from backup...OK

Cleaning up...OK
```

Any ideas how I can fix this?

BTW I'm using this as a guide to install digiKam...
 http://dia-scan.blogspot.com/2013/06/how-to-compile-digikam-32-on-ubuntu-1204.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble; I ended up removing my digiKam directory completely, re-extracting it and then following the instructions here:

http://www.digikam.org/download?q=download/tarball

```
bootstrap.linux
cd build
make
su
make install
```

Not sure exactly what the contents are, but bootstrap.linux, I think, is what made the difference.